# Please join the "000" Corporation channel of or on YouTube?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

> Please join the "0000" Corporation channel of or on YouTube?

My students are evenly split on this sentence. I am using on, but several students are convinced that

> Please join the "0000" Corporation channel of YouTube.

Is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say *on* is appropriate here.

On [can be defined as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on):

> **used as a function word to indicate the location of something**

The channel is hosted using YouTube, so *on* should be used.